# Why is nginx not passing upstream response header to client?

Tags: nginx

I am running an nginx proxy and the server behind it returns 401 with a `WWW-Authenticate` header.

I need to access this header, but nginx does not proxy it back to the client. The client uses this header for doing NTLM auth.

Here's what I have right now:

```
location /foo {
  proxy_pass http://example.com;
  proxy_intercept_errors on;

  add_header WWW-Authenticate $upstream_http_www_authenticate always;
}
```

It is my understand that `$upstream_` should refer to the target server and `http_` -prefix allows to access any HTTP header. Finally, `add_header` should set the response header for the client.

Given all this, why is it not being passed? I'm not getting any errors, it's just that nothing is passed only these headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Mon, 28 Aug 2023 17:01:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 179
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx/1.25.2
```

The actual targer server is responding with:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAABgAGADgAAAAFgomiYKyFDH78wbMAAAAAAAAAAMIAwgA+AAAACgA5OAAAAA9KAFQAWQACAAYASgBUAFkAAQAeAEoAVABZAFYASQBFAFcAMgAxAEkATgBUAE4ARAAxAAQAHgBqAHQAeQAuAG8AawBvAGIAYQBuAGsALgBuAGUAdAADAD4ASgBUAFkAVgBJAEUAVwAyADEASQBOAFQATgBEADEALgBqAHQAeQAuAG8AawBvAGIAYQBuAGsALgBuAGUAdAAFAB4AagB0AHkALgBvAGsAbwBiAGEAbgBrAC4AbgBlAHQABwAIAMY05AnK2dkBAAAAAA==
Date: Mon, 28 Aug 2023 16:09:35 GMT
```